# Python: Getting Element Value from XPath

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, xpath, beautifulsoup

I'm really new at xpaths and web scraping so I apologize if this is a relatively small question to ask. I'm trying to scrape multiple websites in order to make sure data in a database is updated. I am able to get the xPath of a partial string, but am unsure how to get the full value using the xPath.

Code:

```py
def xpath_soup(element):
    components = []
    child = element if element.name else element.parent
    for parent in child.parents:

        previous = itertools.islice(parent.children, 0,parent.contents.index(child))
        xpath_tag = child.name
        xpath_index = sum(1 for i in previous if i.name == xpath_tag) + 1
        components.append(xpath_tag if xpath_index == 1 else '%s[%d]' % (xpath_tag, xpath_index))
        child = parent
    components.reverse()
    return '/%s' % '/'.join(components)



page = requests.get("https://www.gaumard.com/obstetricmr")
html = str(BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser'))
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')
elem = soup.find(string=re.compile('xt-generation mixed reality training solution for VICTORIA® S2200 designed to help learners bridge the gap between theory and practice'))
xPathValue = xpath_soup(elem)
print(xPathValue)
```

I'm trying to get the full value of the element using `xPathValue`.

Expected result would be the full version of
`xt-generation mixed reality training solution for VICTORIA® S2200 designed to help learners bridge the gap between theory and practice`

being

`Obstetric MR™ is a next-generation mixed reality training solution for VICTORIA® S2200 designed to help learners bridge the gap between theory and practice faster than ever before. Using the latest technology in holographic visualization, Obstetric MR brings digital learning content into the physical simulation exercise, allowing participants to link knowledge and skill through an entirely new hands-on training experience. The future of labor and delivery simulation is here.`

This full value would come from utilizing `xPathValue`.

Comment: What should be the expected result?

Comment: @AndrejKesely post has been edited

Comment: So, do you want to use Xpath with `beautifulsoup`? `bs4` has it's own API or is using CSS selectors

Comment: @AndrejKesely it really doesn't matter to me what I use. I've just been trying different things out from other stuff i've seen on stackoverflow

Answer (score 1):

Here's how to get the full text with an `XPath`.

```py
import requests
from lxml import html

page = requests.get("https://www.gaumard.com/obstetricmr").text
text = html.fromstring(page).xpath('//*[@style="margin: 0 auto;"][2]/div/text()')
print(text[0].strip())
```

Output:

```
Obstetric MR™ is a next-generation mixed reality training solution for VICTORIA® S2200 designed to help learners bridge the gap between theory and practice faster than ever before. Using the latest technology in holographic visualization, Obstetric MR brings digital learning content into the physical simulation exercise, allowing participants to link knowledge and skill through an entirely new hands-on training experience. The future of labor and delivery simulation is here.
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. It works, but i'm trying to automate the creation of the xpath so that I can use this code for other websites as well. Is there a way to automate the creation of `//*[@style="margin: 0 auto;"][2]/div/text()`?

Comment: Websites are different and I don't think there's a way to automatically create a valid XPath.

Comment: My method here was to find where part of the string `Obstetric MR™ is a next-generation mixed reality training` was located in the html and find the Xpath based on that. Is this not a good method, or is there a better method?

Answer (score 1):

A specific XPath will not help much since, as said, web pages might be different.
A generic XPath to search text nodes and get arrays or lists of nodes containing that string could help with some post processing.

**Trying on Firefox console:**

```
nodes = $x('//*[contains(text(),"next-generation mixed reality")]', window.document, "nodes");
<- Array [ div ]

nodes[0].textContent;
<- "Obstetric MR™ is a next-generation...(redacted)"
```

This XPath could work on other pages
`'//*[contains(text(),"next-generation mixed reality")]'`
provided that they contain `next-generation mixed reality` string.

**Same using python:**

```
import requests
from lxml import html
url = 'https://www.gaumard.com/obstetricmr'
response = requests.get(url)
html_doc = response.content
xpath0 = '//*[contains(text(),"next-generation mixed reality")]'
result_arr = html.fromstring(html_doc).xpath(xpath0)
result_arr[0].text
```

**Output:**

```
'Obstetric MR™ is a next-generation mixed...'
```

Comment: Hi Luis, i'm a bit confused. I'm looking for Python code, what is above?

Comment: It can be done in any language that uses XPath so the key piece is the xpath itself. Give me some time and I will add a python example (later today).

Comment: @Bob added python example.